# How can I prove this statement about mean and variance?

Tags: probability, statistics

How can I prove that:
$$E(a) = a\, \text{ and }\, V(a) = 0?$$

Comment: This is not clear.  By "$a$" do you mean a constant?  That is, a "random" variable that only takes the value $a$?  If so, just write down the definition of mean and variance and apply it in the usual way.

Comment: Sorry about that, a is a constant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $X$ discrete random variable with constant value $a$. So distribution looks like$$a\space a \space ...a\\p_1\space p_2 \space... p_n$$
Then
$$EX = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a \cdot p_i = a \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i = a$$
Variance in same way.